# how to set (css) border width?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

[image]

*I want to set solid border width like as picture. What can I do? Thanks for answers*

```
      |
      |
-----   -------
      |
      |
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. A little more clarity please?

Comment: Ah cmon guys, these awnsers make no sense.
Fastest way to do this is on the image it self on photoshop. 2nd thing is to make somekind of border div on the outside of the image and make the height and width 96%. Give that class a border

Comment: i want to border like as picture. It should be shorter than its div width. Some hole end of the border. Just look at the center of picture

Comment: Have you looked at the border-image property?  http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Answer (score 6):

You can visually achieve this result if you apply `border-radius` to the parent container.

The child container needs to have a solid background (that matches the background of the wrapper element). Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/JgsKM/

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to do borders like that just by using CSS border properties. You'd have to resort to some kind of trickery to cover over the borders at each corner.

You are better off using a background image for this task. Prepare an image with the right and bottom lines and place it on the background of those rectangles, positioned bottom right on each one. (Obviously you'd prepare the background image so that those gray lines don't meet at the bottom right corner—just as in the image you posted.)

This is assuming that you have a fair idea of the width and height of the elements, so it's not a perfect solution, but will get you pretty close.

Comment: thank you but i dont want to use background image. my prefer is css

Comment: Yes, my point was that it will be a world of pain for you to do that—to the point where it's not worth it, IMHO. You could, for example, set a right and bottom border on the element, and then use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to cover over the corners with a white box, but heck ... is it really worth the trouble? Too hacky for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
img { 
    border:solid rgb(165, 162, 162)
    border-top:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add **4 child divs for mask borders parent div**.

### Html

```
<ul class="list">
<li>
<div id="holder"> <!--parent div--> 
   <div id="maskTopLeft"></div> <!-- child 1 for mask border on top-left --> 
   <div id="maskTopRight"></div> <!-- child 2 for mask border on top-right --> 
   <div id="maskBottomLeft"></div> <!-- child 3 for mask border on bottom-left --> 
   <div id="maskBottomRight"></div> <!-- child 4 for mask border on bottom-right --> 
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

### css

```
#main { width:100%; margin:10px; }

.list {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}
.list li {
  float:left;
  margin-right: -0.5px;
  margin-top: -0.5px;
}
.list li:first-child #holder {
  border-right: 0.5px solid #000;
}
.list li:last-child #holder {
  border-left: 0.5px solid #000;
}
#holder {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
}

#maskTopLeft {
    position: absolute;
    top:-1px;
    left:-1px;
    width:21px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#maskTopRight {
    position: absolute;
    top:-1px;
    left:180px;
    width:21px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#maskBottomRight {
    position: absolute;
    top:230px;
    left:180px;
    width:21px;
    height:21px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#maskBottomLeft {
    position: absolute;
    top:230px;
    left:-1px;
    width:21px;
    height:21px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

<kbd>**[demo on cssdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/wijfwpeb)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-image properties in css the best and easy way

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score -1):

set a backgroud image to the div-container where the images is in it. this background image is white and has the to borders (right side, bottom side) as you want. i think that's the solution for your problem, because otherwise the borders will look different